# Materialized View refresh error. ORA-12018: following error encountered during code generation

Tags: oracle

Oracle fails when performing a fast refresh of a MV that reads from another schema.

SCHEMA_A contains the source table

```sql
create table test_new_20230508 (pname varchar(100) PRIMARY KEY );

insert into TEST_NEW_20230508 (PNAME) values ('some name');

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG ON TEST_NEW_20230508 WITH ROWID, PRIMARY KEY;

grant select on TEST_NEW_20230508 to SCHEMA_B;

commit;
```

on SCHEMA_B we try

```sql
-- ok
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW TEST_NEW_20230508_MV AS select * from SCHEMA_A.TEST_NEW_20230508;
-- ok
SELECT * FROM TEST_NEW_20230508_MV;

-- fails
BEGIN
    DBMS_MVIEW.REFRESH('TEST_NEW_20230508_MV', 'F');
END;
```

the error is

```
[2023-05-08 16:09:25] [72000][12018]
[2023-05-08 16:09:25]   ORA-12018: following error encountered during code generation for "SCHEMA_B"."TEST_NEW_20230508_MV"
[2023-05-08 16:09:25]   ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SNAPSHOT_KKXRCA", line 3020
[2023-05-08 16:09:25]   ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SNAPSHOT_KKXRCA", line 2432
[2023-05-08 16:09:25]   ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
[2023-05-08 16:09:25]   ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SNAPSHOT_KKXRCA", line 88
[2023-05-08 16:09:25]   ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SNAPSHOT_KKXRCA", line 253
[2023-05-08 16:09:25]   ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SNAPSHOT_KKXRCA", line 2413
[2023-05-08 16:09:25]   ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SNAPSHOT_KKXRCA", line 2976
[2023-05-08 16:09:25]   ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SNAPSHOT_KKXRCA", line 3263
[2023-05-08 16:09:25]   ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SNAPSHOT_KKXRCA", line 3295
[2023-05-08 16:09:25]   ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SNAPSHOT", line 16
[2023-05-08 16:09:25]   ORA-06512: at line 2
[2023-05-08 16:09:25] Position: 0
```

The db version is

```sql
select BANNER_FULL from V$VERSION;
```

Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.17.0.0.0

## Note 1 ⚠️

the above works if the mv log is created without the PRIMARY KEY

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG ON TEST_NEW_20230508 WITH ROWID;
```

and the refresh if not FAST

```sql
BEGIN
    DBMS_MVIEW.REFRESH('TEST_NEW_20230508_MV');
END;
```

## Note 2 ⚠️

the FAST refresh works if the MV is in the same source schema SCHEMA_A instead of SCHEMA_B

From `ORA-00942: table or view does not exist` I guess that something goes wrong when SCHEMA_B tries to access some data needed on the MV Log linked to the primary key.

Any additional grants needed to run fast refreshes across schemas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For fast refreshes, you must grant select on the MV Log to `SCHEMA_B` in addition to select on the table TEST_NEW_20230508. The MV Log is a table in its own right.

Answer (score 0):

issue solved by granting select on the log table

```sql
select a.master, a.LOG_TABLE from USER_MVIEW_LOGS a where a.MASTER = 'TEST_NEW_20230508';
```

I hope this will help others. The error message is really opaque.